# Entity Framework Core 7.0 GIN search accuracy

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, postgresql-9.5, inverted-index

I use postgresql with EntityFramework Core 7.0 and build search vector with the default GIN method from 2 columns `Title` and `Description` of Products table, both of type `string`:

```
        builder.HasGeneratedTsVectorColumn(
                   p => p.SearchVector,
                   "english",  // Text search config
                   p => new { p.Title, p.Description })  // Included properties
               .HasIndex(p => p.SearchVector)
               .HasMethod("GIN"); // Index method on the search vector (GIN or GIST)
```

This produces a `SearchVector` column of type `tstype` in the Products table. Taking a closer look, this column contains partial word of the `Title` and/or `Description` columns. For example, the word `glucose` would only have `glucos` in the search vector column.
So, searching for `glucose` keyword in my web application  using `.Where(record => record.p.SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery(keyword)))` would end up with empty result set. This is disappointing or what do I miss?